# How to remove RSS Feed-icon?

Tags: theming, 8

I am using Drupal 8.1.1. I have made a copy of the Bartik theme and enabled that theme and using that as default theme. 
I want to disable the RSS feed-icon. I was hoping to find some control/code in the templates folder to disable the RSS feed icon, but could not find anything like that. (Though there is some reference to feed-icon in theme.libraries.yml).

Can someone suggest how to remove the RSS feed icon in Drupal 8.1.1? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if you **don't want to disable** the feed, but **just remove the icon**.

According to FiNeX comment in [Disable RSS icon in Drupal 8 via Views > Frontpage](https://www.drupal.org/node/2664802#comment-11165725)

> A better way to remove the icon leaving the RSS feed active is to
>   simply disable the feed attachment option.
>
> 1) Structure > Views > Frontpage Edit
>
> 2) Click on "Feed" tab display
>
> 3) Click on "Page" next to "Attach"
>
> 4) Uncheck "Page"
>
> 5) Save

---

Now if you want to **disable** RSS, then

According to couturier in [Disable RSS icon in Drupal 8 via Views > Frontpage](https://www.drupal.org/node/2664802)

> Go to Structure > Views > Frontpage > Edit
>
> Then click on "Feed" at the top. In the second drop-down box, select
>   "Disable Feed." Then "Save" the change.

Comment: For future readers, this is a nice example of how to prevent link-only answers.  Provide the link to the reference, but summarize the basics in the answer.